# Creating jQuery array variable and Transferring array to another page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I currently have this function exactly how I want it except for the jQuery at the bottom in which I am only alerting and not creating a real variable. It all works but I am stuck on how I can take all of the data from the jQuery script and then make it into a variable so that I can bring it to another page? Any ideas, NEED HELP!

```
function getGrade($id, $grades_array) {
        $counter = 0;
        $sql = "Select grade FROM grades";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        echo '<select name="grades_selected" multiple="multiple" id="grades_selected">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                if ($row['grade'] != $grades_array[$counter]) {
                        echo "<option>" . $row['grade'] . "</option>";
                } else {
                        echo "<option selected=" . $row['grade']  . ">" . $row['grade'] . "</option>";
                        $counter = $counter + 1;
                }
        }
    mysql_free_result($result);
        echo '</select>';
        $_SESSION['test'] = $grades_array;
        ?>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#grades_selected').change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());
                });
                });
        </script>
<?

}
```

Comment: define your expectations regarding `bring it to another page`

Comment: I just want it to create an array with the selected values and then take that array and use it on another page once they hit submit on the form

Comment: won't those values be submitted also? Is form being submitted through browser default process?

Comment: Sorry new to all of this, pretty much is there any way to take the jQuery array that the function creates and make it into a session variable?

Comment: if you submit the form conventionally, you would simply take the data submitted to pass into next page. This will be simplest route.

Comment: The form is initially populated from a database so I am just stuck on trying to make it update if changes are made.

Comment: then what does `use on another page` mean? If all you need is to update db then use answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax within on change function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#grades_selected').change(function() {
 var variable = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'target_page.php',
     data: {variable : variable},
     success: function (res) {
         alert(res);
     }
 });
});
});
```

On `target_page.php`:

```
echo $_POST['variable'];
```

Comment: Where would I add this code and how do I link it to the code above?

Comment: unless this is going to be stored in session it doesn't answer how to use it on another page